# Apollo client does not use the expected uri to connect the remote GraphQL server

Tags: graphql, apollo

I am new to Apollo. I set the uri for the remote GraphQL server as instructed in the Apollo documentation: [Apollo Angular Doc: Setup and options](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/setup/#request-data)

```
const uri = 'http://ip_address:port_number/.../graphql';
```

But I got the following error when trying to send a post request to the remote server:

```
POST http://localhost:4200/ 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask    @   zone-evergreen.js:2845
scheduleTask    @   zone-evergreen.js:385
...
```

Looks like the uri I set in graphql.module.ts has no effect. Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: How is the `uri` variable actually being used inside the module?

Answer (score 0):

I did some try and error and found that the problem is gone if I changed the single quote to double quote when specifying the uri:

```
const uri = "http://ip_address:port_number/.../graphql";
```

Hope it will help other people running into the same issue.